# Firefox developer edition 52.0a2 does not have a Variable Pane or a watch expression. Where did it go?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

just installed Dev Edition and am following the videos and documentation but there is no Variable Window and there is now way to watch or modify any variables when debugging javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in MDN section "How to" : [Examine, modify, and watch variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Examine,_modify,_and_watch_variables)

> This feature isn't yet supported in the new debugger. If you need to
>   use it, you can, for now, switch back to the old debugger by visiting
>   about:config and setting the "devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend"
>   preference to false.
>
> To see the docs for the old debugger, please visit [Debugger (before
>   Firefox 52)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger_%28before_Firefox_52%29).

Also, keep in mind that in Firefox Developer Edition, some features are experimental and not fully functional (cf. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Developer_Edition)).